# Process image with android opengl es but output image is weird in a certain device

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es, fbo, grafika

I wrote a demo about camera which is similar to ContinuousCaptureActivity of grafika ([Source code of ContinuousCaptureActivity.java](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)). For every frame, I added some operations besides drawing the frame to screen.

I create a fbo, then bind it and draw the frame to the fbo. In order to check the image rendered to the fbo, I read back the image data back to RAM using pbo and save the image as jpg every 50 frames.
In this way, I got the jpg file but it was scaled, picture is as follows:
[image]

I supposed the matrix from SurfaceTexture caused the scaling because every drawFrame() applied that matrix.So I created anothter fbo and draw the frame of the first fbo to this fbo, then I save the image as jpg and the image turn OK as expected. Look at this one:
[image]

So the conclusion is that 2 draws will restore the image correctly.

But the image is weird in a huawei phone of mine(model:huawei MT7-CL00). Look at it:
[image]

I have checked the image of the first fbo with the huawei phone, it is scaled as expected but not weird. So I think the error ocurred in the scecond fbo. But I can not figure out the reason. Who can give me some advices?

Some source codes:

fbo definitions:

```
private GlTexture mGlTexture;
private GlFrameBuffer mGlFrameBuffer;
private GlFrameBuffer mGlFrameBuffer1;
```

GlTexture and GlFrameBuffer class source codes:

http://www.paste.org/80680

bindFbo method:

```
private void bindFBO(int fbo)
{
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.continuousCapture_surfaceView);
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
}
```

the key codes in  drawFrame():

```
            mDisplaySurface.makeCurrent();
    mCameraTexture.updateTexImage();
    mCameraTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTmpMatrix);

    // Fill the SurfaceView with it.
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.continuousCapture_surfaceView);
    int viewWidth = 640;
    int viewHeight = 480;
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
    //drawExtra(mFrameNum, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    mDisplaySurface.swapBuffers();


    bindFBO(mGlFrameBuffer.getID());
    mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
    bindFBO(mGlFrameBuffer1.getID());
    mFullFrameBlit2d.drawFrame(mGlTexture.getID(), mTmpMatrix);

    String filename = "/sdcard/test/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    new File(filename).getParentFile().mkdirs();
    if (mFrameNum % 50 == 0)
    {
        try {
            getPixelFromPBO(viewWidth, viewHeight, filename);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Curious... there's a jagged diagonal line through the image, and it seems to be reflected around that line. Are you somehow copying a buffer onto itself?

Comment: It only occurs on the huawei mate7 phone.  I often come up with such kind of things, this is the feature of android.

Comment: My thought was that it might be a race condition, and the device in question happens to lose the race. OTOH, it wouldn't be the first bug anyone found in a GLES driver. The upside of a race condition is that it's something you can fix.

Comment: @fadden
Please have a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236964/how-to-understand-the-underneath-of-setdisplay-setsurface-setprewviewdisplay-set